# Loading the last View Controller Active after app goes into background, swift

Tags: ios, swift, background-mode

I have "Tinder" like swipping view that is located in a CardViewController. The card View Controller is accessed by moving through two other view controllers. i.e. Load App  -> FirstViewController -> SecondViewController - > CardViewController.

When I am in the Card ViewController and I go into background mode, the app launches on the FirstViewController and on going to the cards, they are loaded from the first card in a stack of about 10?

Is there anyway to load the app from the last Card I had swipped and in the CardViewController without having to navigate from the FirstView Controller again?

I would really appreciate the help as it's horribly affecting some of my users.

An example of a Tinder like card view is shown!

Comment: Have you looked into the [Preserving and Restoring State](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html) guide?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, from the sound of it, is not what happens when the app goes into the background — that would leave it in exactly the same state when it reactivates. The problem is what happens when the app goes into the background *and quits*. Your app is then relaunched from scratch, which is why you find yourself in the first view controller. What's upsetting you is the *difference* between the app's behavior in these two situations.

Apple provides a solution to this situation: UIViewController, along with the App Delegate, has methods permitting you to *save and restore state*. When the app goes into the background, the current configuration (what view controller's view is showing) is saved. That way, even when the app quits, when it relaunches it can get back to that configuration before it appears to the user. Thus, coming back from background-and-quit looks just like coming back from mere backgrounding.

For full details, see Apple's documentation. This is a good place to start:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely dig into this.

Comment: I've got plenty of downloadable sample code projects that you can look at, once you've decided this is the way to go. This one is the first of several: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch06p341SimplestRestorationExample

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a lot. They will certainly be useful. :]